# C++ cin.ignore() works even when used after getline(), but why?

Tags: c++

I am teaching an after school club about cin and getline() right now and I know you're suppose to put a cin.ignore() when switching from cin and getline; I also know why we do that, it all makes sense.

However.... A student put cin.ignore() AFTER the getline() call and it still worked as if they put it before getline(), does anyone know why?

What I teach and what I know works.

```
string answer, line; 
cin >> answer; 
cin.ignore(); 
getline(cin, line);
```

What shouldn't work but does even though cin.ignore is after getline()?

```
string answer, line; 
cin >> answer; 
getline(cin, line); 
cin.ignore();
```

Comment: I would say that answering this requires a [mcve] and the (verbatim) relevant input.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with exact input, expected output and actual output. That way, we will also be able to see how you are determining that "it works".

Comment: `AFTER the getline() call and it still worked as if they put it before getline()` pelase define that something "worked". As mention above provide [mcve] and remember to provide example of an input.
Anyway first example is wrong! It will not work if user ends line with extra space.

Comment: Did you check what was in `line` when the `ignore()` was put _after_ `getline`? Are you on Windows?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you forgot to add `'\n'` otherwise you will discard whole input.

Comment: You should change `cin.ignore();` to`cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );`, to solve the issue of possible extra whitespace at the end of the line. Note that in a previous (deleted) comment of mine, I had made a mistake and my solution was wrong. The second parameter was missing. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @MarekR: Yes, you are right. I have fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out. (I had to delete and repost my comment, because the 5 minutes editing time was over).

Comment: My apologies for not providing a minimal reproducible example. I will make sure to do that in the future. Thank you very much for all of your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Please read carefully how `operator>>` works, and what `ignore()` does.

- by default, `operator>>` discards leading whitespace characters before extracting data needed for a value. This can be disabled with `std::noskipws`.
- `operator>>` for integer types extracts as many characters as possible to interpret them as an integer.
- `operator>>` for a string extracts only non-whitespace characters. Reading stops just before the first whitespace character.
- by default, `.ignore()` discards just a single character.
- to trim a line after `operator>>`, ignore should be used as: `.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

This leads to the following cases:

| type | input | read effect | remaining input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `int` | `11` | 11 |  |
| `int` | `12` | 12 |  |
| `int` | `1\n` | 1 | `\n` |
| `int` | `1 \n` | 1 | `\n` |
| `int` | `13das` | 13 | `das` |
| `std::string` | `foo` | "foo" |  |

Your first example will fail if `line` ends with extra spaces.

Your second example may appear to be working if input contains leading whitespace, or other characters which are skipped do not have impact on reading the result (for example: `+12` when reading `int`).